# Java Code Review: Merge sorted lists into a single sorted list

Tags: java, list, sorting

I want to merge sorted lists into a single list. How is this solution? I believe it runs in O(n) time. Any glaring flaws, inefficiencies, or stylistic issues?

I don't really like the idiom of setting a flag for "this is the first iteration" and using it to make sure "lowest" has a default value. Is there a better way around that?

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> List<T> merge(Set<List<T>> lists) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();

    int totalSize = 0; // every element in the set
    for (List<T> l : lists) {
        totalSize += l.size();
    }

    boolean first; //awkward
    List<T> lowest = lists.iterator().next(); // the list with the lowest item to add

    while (result.size() < totalSize) { // while we still have something to add
        first = true;

        for (List<T> l : lists) {
            if (! l.isEmpty()) {
                if (first) {
                    lowest = l;
                    first = false;
                }
                else if (l.get(0).compareTo(lowest.get(0)) <= 0) {
                    lowest = l;
                }
            }
        }
        result.add(lowest.get(0));
        lowest.remove(0);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note: this isn't homework, but it isn't for production code, either.

Comment: I think your implementation is fine, but a note about the algorithmic complexity: Assuming a constant number of input lists, it's O(n).  But since your method can handle an arbitrary number of input lists, the run-time is O(M*n) - you have to take into account the variable number of lists.  If M > log2(n)+1 (I think), it would actually be faster to simply concatenate all the lists and mergesort them, which takes O(n*log2(n)).  This isn't likely to be the case very often, but it's worth noting.

Comment: This is standard merge-sort code. You can probably find inspiration for a way to optimize your loop at http://www.google.com/codesearch#search/&q=merge%5C%20sort&type=cs . You shouldn't need to have that 'first' boolean.

Comment: @Rosarch: I'd suggest not to remove anything - as already stated `remove(0)` is a disaster for an `ArrayList`, but for any `List` it takes needlessly time. Maintaining a `Set<Iterator>` (or an array of indexes for maximum speed) should be better. Since Java has got TimSort it's probably better to simply concat the lists and call sort.

Comment: destructive to input.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks for a code review, which should be on [codereview.se]


Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution is probably the fastest one. SortedLists have an insert cost of log(n), so you'll end up with M log (M) (where M is the total size of the lists).

Adding them to one list and sorting, while easier to read, is still M log(M).

Your solution is just M.

You can clean up your code a bit by sizing the result list, and by using a reference to the lowest list instead of a boolean.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> List<T> merge(Set<List<T>> lists) {
    int totalSize = 0; // every element in the set
    for (List<T> l : lists) {
        totalSize += l.size();
    }

    List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>(totalSize);

    List<T> lowest;

    while (result.size() < totalSize) { // while we still have something to add
        lowest = null;

        for (List<T> l : lists) {
            if (! l.isEmpty()) {
                if (lowest == null) {
                    lowest = l;
                } else if (l.get(0).compareTo(lowest.get(0)) <= 0) {
                    lowest = l;
                }
            }
        }

        result.add(lowest.get(0));
        lowest.remove(0);
    }

    return result;
}
```

If you're really particular, use a List object as input, and lowest can be initialized to be lists.get(0) and you can skip the null check.

Answer (score 13):

Efficiency will suck if `lists` contains an ArrayList, since `lowest.remove(0)` will take linear time in the length of the list, making your algorithm O(n^2).

I'd do:

```
List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
for (List<T> list : lists) {
    result.addAll(list);
}
Collections.sort(result);
```

which is in O(n log n), and leaves far less tedious code to test, debug and maintain.

Comment: There's a slight problem with this answer. When creating a new `ArrayList` without specifying it's capacity, it will have to grow as more elements are added. Each time it grows it will need to copy it's entire contents to a new array, which is O(n). For m arrays, it potentially adds O(m*n) (but this depends on the `ArrayList`'s growth policy and initial capacity). To easily avoid this issue we can first sum the size of all `lists` and then specify the initial capacity for the `result` list.

Comment: Since the Javadoc writes "The details of the growth policy are not specified beyond the fact that adding an element has constant amortized time cost.", you'd speed up adding elements by a small constant factor, but that's not the expensive part of this algorithm, so the overall effect will be negligible. Specifically, with the growth policy of the oracle implementation, the runtime would be about 3n array elements being copied rather n, while the second part will involve about n log n comparisions, each of which will be significantly more expensive than copying an array element.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on Anton's comment:

By placing the latest result from each List, along with an indicator of whch list it is, into a heap, then continually take the top off the heap, and put a new item on the heap from the list belonging to the item you just took off.

Java's PriorityQueue can provide the heap implementation.

Answer (score 4):

This is a really old question, but I don't like any of the submitted answers, so this is what I ended up doing.

The solution of just adding them all into one list and sorting is bad because of the log linear complexity (`O(m n log(m n))`). If that's not important to you, then it's definitely the simplest and most straightforward answer. Your initial solution isn't bad, but it's a little messy, and  @Dathan pointed out that the complexity is `O(m n)` for m lists and n total elements. You can reduce this to `O(n log(m))` by using a heap to reduce the number of comparisons for each element. I use a helper class that allows me to compare iterables. This way I don't destroy the initial lists, and it should operate with reasonable complexity no matter what type of lists are input. The only flaw I see with the implementation below is that it doesn't support lists with `null` elements, however this could be fixed with sentinels if desired.

```
public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> List<E> merge(Collection<? extends List<? extends E>> lists) {
    PriorityQueue<CompIterator<E>> queue = new PriorityQueue<CompIterator<E>>();
    for (List<? extends E> list : lists)
        if (!list.isEmpty())
            queue.add(new CompIterator<E>(list.iterator()));

    List<E> merged = new ArrayList<E>();
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        CompIterator<E> next = queue.remove();
        merged.add(next.next());
        if (next.hasNext())
            queue.add(next);
    }
    return merged;
}

private static class CompIterator<E extends Comparable<? super E>> implements Iterator<E>, Comparable<CompIterator<E>> {
    E peekElem;
    Iterator<? extends E> it;

    public CompIterator(Iterator<? extends E> it) {
        this.it = it;
        if (it.hasNext()) peekElem = it.next();
        else peekElem = null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return peekElem != null;
    }

    @Override
    public E next() {
        E ret = peekElem;
        if (it.hasNext()) peekElem = it.next();
        else peekElem = null;
        return ret;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(CompIterator<E> o) {
        if (peekElem == null) return 1;
        else return peekElem.compareTo(o.peekElem);
    }

}
```

Every element of the returned list involves two O(log(m)) heap operations, there is also an initial iteration over all of the lists. Therefore the overall complexity is O(n log(m) + m) for n total elements and m lists. making this always faster than concatenating and sorting.

Comment: Yes, a heap based k-way merge is definitely the way to go for a performance hotspot. But it is also harder to develop, debug and maintain, so I'd only use it after measuring that the simple algorithm is not fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

Since Balus and meriton have together given an excellent response to your question about the algorithm, I'll speak to your aside about the "first" idiom.

There are definitely other approaches (like setting lowest to a 'magic' value), but I happen to feel that "first" (to which I'd probably give a longer name, but that's being pedantic) is the best, because it's very clear.  Presence of a boolean like "first" is a clear signal that your loop will do something special the first time through.  It helps the reader.

Of course you don't need it if you take the Balus/meriton approach, but it's a situation which crops up.