# Merge already sorted LinkedList in java

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, linked-list

I got a question saying merge already sorted 2 linkedList and get the final output as Sorted LinkedList.
So I used the merge method of Merge Sort algorithm and got the output ,
Is it actually the right way to do it or I should follow some other way.

Here is the piece of code for understanding-

```
private <T extends Comparable<T>> List<T> merge(List<T> left , List<T> right){
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    while(left.size()>0 && right.size()>0){
        //Left is less than right
        if(left.get(0).compareTo(right.get(0))<0)
            result.add(left.remove(0)); //add the left if small and remove it from the list             
        else
            result.add(right.remove(0));
    }

    //if left size is greater than 0 , the needed to add left to result
    //it proves that if any of the sizes of left/right is more then those are greater size
    if(left.size()>0)
        result.addAll(left);
    else
        result.addAll(right);


    return result;
}
```

My Input -

```
 List<String> sorted1 = new LinkedList<String>();
            sorted1.add("Asdsd");
            sorted1.add("ReR");
            sorted1.add("asdasd");
            sorted1.add("ghjhj");
            sorted1.add("zxcxc");
            List<String> sorted2 = new LinkedList<String>();
            sorted2.add("Awdf");
            sorted2.add("Gautom");
            sorted2.add("asa");
            sorted2.add("ggg");
            sorted2.add("qwq");
            sorted2.add("rtrt");

            System.out.println("ORIGINAL SoRTED LIST\n" + 
                    "=================\n" +
                    sorted1 + "and "+sorted2+"\n");
            List<String> sorted_String2 = new MergeSortAbhishek().merge(sorted1,sorted2);
            System.out.println("\nFINAL SORTED LIST\n" +
                    "=================\n" +
                    sorted_String2 + "\n");
```

Comment: Can u go through this? Might be of some help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774256/java-code-review-merge-sorted-lists-into-a-single-sorted-list

Comment: What do you mean by merge method of Merge Sort algorithm? Have you implemented it by yourself or used some existing?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds right to me. Can't say for sure without seeing the code that you mean by the "merge arg from merge sort" but the concept is correct.

FYI, this would be a more appropriate question for the Code Review site.

[CodeReview Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd prefer using special method which does exactly merging 2 sorted lists. `merge` method from `MergeSortAbhishek` may confuse because you don't sort anything. And this method may do some special actions for sort.