# Sort List of Objects in Java

Tags: java, sorting, merge, mergesort

I have 6 list of Objects in Java with a data structure like this:

```
Class MyObj {
    int identifier;
    Class someOtherClass;
}
```

Every List in the 6 Lists is a `List<MyObj>`.

I want to build a final list which does merge sort while reading all the 6 lists and prepare a final list.

I believe Merge Sort or similar solution is the way to go. I looked at comparator example as well but could not find one matching my requirements. Can someone suggest a library or existing API that can help me accomplish this task?

I also found a solution at [How to Sort a List<T> by a property in the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309188/how-to-sort-a-listt-by-a-property-in-the-object) but it does inArray sort, it does not tke account of multiple Lists.

**All 6 Lists are already Sorted, I need combined sorted List**

Comment: Are your 6 lists already sorted?  If not, you might as well combine into one list before using a normal sort.

Comment: @searlea they are already sorted, that's why I was thinking of a solution like MergeSort.

Comment: Did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1775748/98493 ?

Comment: Just concatenate the 6 lists and sort the resulting list. Only optimize if you really have a performance problem.

Comment: @JBNizet the list is huge, it will have 1000's of elements.

Comment: Sorting the concatenation of 6 sorted lists of 10,000 random integers takes 9 milliseconds on my machine. Is that worth optimizing? Measure before optimizing. Computers are fast.