# Split huge Json objects for saving into database

Tags: java, json, postman

I have a JSON file which contains around 20000 objects.

I would like to split the file into parts each containing a smaller number of object but without using any external libraries.

My current json

```
  [{"alt_party_id_type":"xyz","first_name":"child1ss","status":"1","dob":"2014-10-02 
     00:00:00.0","last_name":"childSs"},
    {"alt_party_id_type":"xyz","first_name":"suga","status":"1","dob":"2014-11-05 
      00:00:00.0","last_name":"test"},
           {"alt_party_id_type":"xyz","first_name":"test4a","status":"1","dob":"2000-11-05 
       00:00:00.0","last_name":"test4s"},
             {"alt_party_id_type":"xyz","first_name":"demo56","status":"0","dob":"2000-11-04 
    00:00:00.0","last_name":"Demo5"}, 
  {"alt_party_id_type":"xyz","first_name":"testsss","status":"1","dob":"1900-01-01 
     00:00:00.0","last_name":"testssssssssss"}, 
    {"alt_party_id_type":"xyz","first_name":"Demo1234","status":"0","dob":"2014-11-21 
  00:00:00.0","last_name":"Demo1"}, 
   {"alt_party_id_type":"xyz","first_name":"demo2433","status":"1","dob":"2014-11-13 
   00:00:00.0","last_name":"demo222"}, 
 {"alt_party_id_type":"xyz","first_name":"demo333","status":"0","dob":"2014-11-12 
00:00:00.0","last_name":"demo344"}, 
{"alt_party_id_type":"xyz","first_name":"Student","status":"1","dob":"2001-12-03 
 00:00:00.0","last_name":"StudentTest"}]

if split I need it to look like below
    
    
      - [
                {
                    "alt_party_id_type": "xyz",
                    "first_name": "demo56",
                    "status": "0",
                    "dob":"2000-11-04 
         00: 00: 00.0","last_name":"Demo5"}, 
         {
                        "alt_party_id_type": "xyz",
                        "first_name": "testsss",
                        "status": "1",
                        "dob":"1900-01-01 
             00: 00: 00.0","last_name":"testssssssssss"}, 
            {
                            "alt_party_id_type": "xyz",
                            "first_name": "Demo1234",
                            "status": "0",
                            "dob":"2014-11-21 
            00: 00: 00.0","last_name":"Demo1"}]
```

Comment: Will this work if we split this into a 100 files, each with 200 objects in an array and feed those in one by one to the API ?

Comment: I don't think so. It is failing. Not sure on what approach is suitable

Comment: Why does it fail ? What's the error ?

Comment: Gateway timeout after trying to process 100 array objects through postman

Comment: This is part of data migration from json to database using API

Comment: >  I tried running them through postman of around 100 array of objects but it failed
How exactly did it fail ?

Comment: Basically we connect to different api's of another apps internally which needs to be updated in the table . IT threw timeout error when it failed to response. I just ran around with 25 objects and I got the response

Comment: OK, so you just need to break it down into batches of around 25 objects and them import them individually. This gives us about 800 batches. Can be done manually more or less or by using Gson to split the whole thing

Comment: So I have the 20000 objects in .json file and how can I split it

Comment: Either manually copy pasting parts of it into new files. Or programmatically by reading it into RAM and writing it out to multiple files and sending it.

Comment: Manual could be bit tough as there are around 150 .json files with 20000 object each.

Comment: Then, let's go for an automated solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49273660/how-to-cut-up-large-json-file-into-chunks-and-sort-using-gson

Comment: Can I try using Jq streaming. Not sure. I am just figuring out

Comment: "As this is a standalone program I want to do it without any Json library" Whut.

Comment: It's not hard to code something to split it into individual objects.  If you can read the whole string (good for a few hundred MB) you could then post just a few items at a time.  If you wanted to read the file via a stream you need to work a bit harder, say buffer 1MB at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Since your objects are simple (no sub objects or arrays) you can take your json string and just search for the next "{" then the next "}" and extract the json for that object.  Do it in a loop, incrementing your position in a string. Package as many as you like with "[" and "]" and you have split your array. Process each package within the loop.

Comment: Actually some other files do have some nested object. Like array inside another

Comment: See revised answer

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is write a program, which does the following ...

1. Parse the big JSON file without loading it into memory like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54817985/how-to-parse-a-huge-json-file-without-loading-it-in-memory)
2. Then you read out the data from it in increments of 100-200 and send to the API

You can also do the file split manually by using [this](https://realguess.net/2014/05/18/split-a-large-json-file-into-smaller-pieces/) approach and then import via Postman